# draw something in vsx

Tags: vsx

I found this picture [image: comment], I am curious that how the adornment can draw into to vs text editor. My First Sense is that we can get the text window handle and then draw what we what. But I tried to sub-class text window, I can get the handle but my sub-class window doesn't get any window messages.
Or does someone has any other idea about how to implement this? TIA.

Comment: thanks for asking this; I too need to know how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

I have posted your question on MSDN Forum at [Getting Graphics of the text editor window](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/38374f88-f640-4d7e-84f7-3edeb24e50a5/) thread, and got a reply from [Ed Dore](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/ed%20dore/) (Microsoft) explaining it. Please have a look at the thread above.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. Actually, I have also got the response from Ed Dore at [Is it possible to paint in vs2008 code window](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/5b626cd7-3191-4542-83a5-ad0c8a03bee9)